# Mobx store not injected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

i try do that Store objet
UserStore.js

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

class UserStore {

    constructor() {
        const me = observable({
            me: null,
            auth: action.bound(function(me) {
                this.me = me;
            })
        })
    }
}

export default UserStore;
```

After this, i do that

App.js

```
   const App = inject('routing','UserStore')(observer(class App extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.handleFiles = this.handleFiles.bind(this);
        this.prepareTable = this.prepareTable.bind(this);
        this.state = {excel: null};
    }

    render() {
        const {location, push, goBack} = this.props.routing;
        const {userStore} = this.props.userStore;
```

And in index.js i do

```
    const stores = {
    // Key can be whatever you want
    routing: routingStore,
    UserStores
};

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, routingStore);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider {...stores}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Entry/>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Lets, after all of this i try open the localhost:3000 and se this error

> Error: MobX observer: Store 'UserStore' is not available! Make sure it is provided by some Provider

UPDATE:
I'm create a project with create-react-app, and i can't use @ in code(example for @injector)

Comment: You have written `UserStores` instead of `UserStore`. Also try to export an instance of the UserStore, and not the class itself: `export default new UserStore();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should return an instance of the store.
To be a bit more organized I have a file like "storeInitializer.ts" (using typescript here):

```
import YourStoreName from '../yourStoreFolder/yourStore';

export default function initializeStores() {
    return {
        yourStoreName: new YourStoreName(),
    }
}
```

Then I have another file like "storeIdentifier.ts":

```
export default class Stores {
    static YourStoreName: string = 'yourStoreName';
}
```

In the app file I do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import Stores from './storeIdentifier';

const App = inject(Stores.YourStoreName)(observer(props: any) => {
    //code here
});

export default App;
```

or if you are using the class component approach...

```
import React from 'react';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';

@inject(Stores.YourStoreName)
@observable
class App extends Component {
    //code here
}

export default App;
```